# Redis subscribe while scaling microservices. How to make only one of it process the request?

Tags: docker, redis, microservices, load-balancing, publish-subscribe

I have API server as microservice with 3 replicas. I'm using redis subscribe in my api server. On message received, all the replicas are processing the published message. How can i stop three of them from processing the message, and make only one of the replicas process the message.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this: https://www.vinsguru.com/redis-reactive-stream-real-time-producing-consuming-streams-with-spring-boot/

Comment: Really helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With redis pub-sub all subscribers will get the message. I recommend to use Redis Streams, which is a new offering and allows you to control message distribution between consumers using the concept of Consumer Groups.

https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro